# How to use conditional breakpoint for foreach-loop in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I want to know how to use a conditional breakpoint in eclipse. I have a code like:

```
for(A a:aList){}
```

I have already put a breakponit on the line and I have setted the condition

```
a.getXxx.equals("yyy")
```

but eclipse show me a error:

```
Conditional breakpoint has compliation error(s).
Reason:
a cannot be resolved
```

please help me find the reason.

Comment: You must probably put the breakpoint inside the loop, and not on the foreach loop.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code

Answer (score 4):

you have to place the breakpoint in the first row within in the loop, as a will not be known on the line of the loop yet. So for

```
List<Object> myObjects = ...;
for (Object obj : myObjects ) {
    obj.doSth();
}
```

you would place the breakpoint on the line which is "`obj.doSth();`"

This is actually due to the fact that for the foreach loop the compiler does nothing else than a call to the Iterator.next(); method as the first statement in the loop (you wont notice that as the compiler does it automatically).
Have a look at the java spec:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.14.2

Comment: It works.I just set the breakpoint on the line "for(xxx)".Thankyou.